# EC2 User Data runs script but does not boot up application

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I have a custom AMI that has my app directory and a docker image. I'm setting up Auto Scale Group with Launch Configuration to create a new instance. I have a User Data script to boot up the application. This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose -f /home/ec2-user/app/docker-compose.yaml up -d app
```

the script runs, but the app doesn't run. I can SSH and run the app manually which works. Looking at the cloud-init-output.log file, I'm getting the following:

`/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 4: docker-compose: command not found`

Docker-compose is available when I SSH as I've installed it before creating my custom AMI.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: docker-compose might have been available to the user you used to SSH it your instance (like ec2-user, ubuntu or admin), but it might not be available to root, and root is the one used with user-data when Amazon spins a new instance.
So you might want to add a soft link of docker-compose in your $PATH.

Comment: Thanks @HakRou. It's weird that the `root` `$PATH` does not include `/usr/local/bin` - my two options are either to include `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` in the user data, or install docker-compose in `/usr/bin` instead. Not sure which one is more "best practice"

Comment: I would install docker-compose in /usr/bin, or simply create a symbolic link to it in that folder. It doensn't really matter.
If my comment helped, I'll turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter regarding your best practice question. Either way would suffice.

HakRou is right however.

The boot strap is operating under a different security context / shell environment so you need to cater for that.

You could just put the entire path to the binary file as well such as:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /home/ec2-user/app/docker-compose.yaml up -d app
```

and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose might have been available to the user you used to SSH into your instance (like ec2-user, ubuntu or admin), but it might not be available to root, and root is the one used with user-data when Amazon spins a new instance.

So you might want to add a soft link of docker-compose in one of the folders in the root $PATH, `/usr/bin` for exemple.